# how to give 100% height for table in html5

Tags: css, html

How to give 100% height for table,

```
<table border="1" style="height:100%"><tr> <td>Height 100%</td></tr>  </table>
```

i tried this but its not taking 100% height,
can any one help me

Comment: What CSS do you have on the page, this is likely to be that the Page Body (or any elements that the table is within), isn't set to 100% height. You can use http://www.jsbin.com to paste your HTML & CSS code into, and send over the link to allow us to debug further.

Comment: I am using inside body, now i given 100% to body tag, its working & thanks for providing jsbin.com link to check my html code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give your body the height of `100%` and the table will follow - http://jsfiddle.net/R3h3p/

Comment: It should be noted that the html element will also have to be set to height:100%, not just the body (your link is correct tho). At least in my experiments. I presume this is because html is the parent to body. (Which I find rather odd, that the html and/or body tags dont assume to take up full height of the visible page...Just call me a Quirky kind of guy...lol)

Comment: Trizkit's comment is correct. However, don't forget also that not only do the `html` and `body` elements have to have `height: 100%`, but *all parent elements* of the table must have `height: 100%` as well.